# Can’t Override Default Cancel Intent

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there anyway that I can add a custom message when user says ‘Cancel’ or ‘Exit’ to end the conversation?
I have added intent for these utterances and connected it with my webhook but the message I send back in app.ask() is not displayed or read.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a known issue and you cannot override these words currently. You can handle handle other words like "quit", "finish", "exit", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Done using API.AI. (see the picture)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O927o.png

Answer (score 0):

As per this specification

[Conversation Exit google assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits)

probably you will only able to do an  app.tell() in your webhoook because this must be a final Intent (you can tell something to user but not ask and waiting for a response), see point five of suggested configuration:

> Enable Set this intent as end of conversation

In every case if you use a weebhhok take care: The maximum execution time allowed for conversation exit requests is 2 seconds